# Density of normal elements in a C*- algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra.
I wanted to know if there is a necessary and sufficient condition for normal elements to be dense in $A$?

Comment: Isn't this a closed condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal elements of any $C^*$-algebra $A$ are norm-closed in $A$. Indeed, if $\{a_n\}_n$ is a sequence of normal elements with $a= \lim_n a_n$, then by joint continuity of multiplication and involution,
$$aa^* = \lim_n a_n a_n^* = \lim_n a_n^* a_n = a^*a.$$

Hence, your question is equivalent with: when is every element of a $C^*$-algebra normal?

By the comment of @Jochen Glueck below, this is only the case when $A$ is commutative.

Comment: It is only satisfied in the commutative case: if, for $a$ and $b$ self-adjoint, the element $a+ib$ is normal, then $a$ and $b$ commute.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thank you. I edited the answer.